# Conditional row formatting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have managed to get **all** the rows to change to a `LightCyan` color and now only want to select the column `BusType` which is either `CUS` or `SUP` that displays the color.

I have looked at many references and found this one to work:

[ASPxGridView.HtmlRowPrepared Event](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_HtmlRowPreparedtopic)

however, when you use it like:

```
if (e.GetValue("BusType") == "CUS")
    {
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
    }
```

Nothing happens.

My front end code looks like this (not fully copied and pasted):

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" KeyFieldName="CompanyID;BusinessID" OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="ASPxGridView1_HtmlDataCellPrepared"
        EnableTheming="True" Theme="Office2010Black">
        <Settings ShowFilterRow="True" />
        <SettingsBehavior AutoFilterRowInputDelay="500" />
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" 
                ShowNewButtonInHeader="True" VisibleIndex="0" ShowClearFilterButton="True">
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="BusType" VisibleIndex="3">
```

Does anyone know how I can identify the value of the `BusType` column for each of the rows I have (532 rows).

EDIT: I receive no errors in the above code but adding the `if` statement removed **all** the Cyan highlighted rows and **did not** replace only the `CUS` with it - it all went back to no formatting.

EDIT: I have this code in my Namespace area: `public bool ProcessSelectionChangedOnServer { get; set; }`

Comment: how is this question related to entity framework , linq ??

Comment: Its the Framework I am using so I put it in there in-case it effected the way a GridView functioned. Apologies if it was irrelivant, I'll remove that now. @vishalsharma

Comment: No, it is not. It is the framework you use to RETRIEVE Data. Your question has nothing to do with data retrieval at all.

Comment: Noted, thanks @TomTom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, was an easy fix - I had to add `.ToString()` which converts to allow the match of type string to string.

Reference: [Conversion .ToString()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (e.GetValue("BusType").ToString() == "CUS")
    {
        e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightCyan;
    }
```